# Pod not getting created due to Volume Count

Tags: azure-aks, sql-server-2019

All,

I tried setting up a SQLServer BDC on my personal account on Azure with Standard_E4s_v3. I had requested them to increase the vCPU from 10 max earlier and that is how I have been able to get this far.

However, this time, the deployment seems to be stuck while creating the sparkhead-0 pod. I checked the pod's description and below is what I got:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  51s (x43 over 61m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) exceed max volume count.
```

Does this mean that I have to request an increase in the number of drives? It seems a bit odd that an Odd number of VMs (3) could result in Even number of Drives (26) **(3 * 8) + 2)**

Below is the status of the various Pods

```
C:\Users\rgn>kubectl get pods -n mssql-cluster
NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
appproxy-pgmhq    2/2     Running   0          67m
compute-0-0       3/3     Running   0          67m
control-gm6nh     3/3     Running   0          75m
controldb-0       2/2     Running   0          75m
controlwd-rc4g2   1/1     Running   0          71m
data-0-0          3/3     Running   0          67m
data-0-1          3/3     Running   0          67m
gateway-0         2/2     Running   0          66m
logsdb-0          1/1     Running   0          71m
logsui-7qhp8      1/1     Running   0          71m
master-0          3/3     Running   0          66m
metricsdb-0       1/1     Running   0          71m
metricsdc-2mc7w   1/1     Running   0          71m
metricsdc-fw96x   1/1     Running   0          71m
metricsdc-xgnmh   1/1     Running   0          71m
metricsui-spd2v   1/1     Running   0          71m
mgmtproxy-bmkld   2/2     Running   0          71m
nmnode-0-0        2/2     Running   0          67m
sparkhead-0       0/4     Pending   0          66m
storage-0-0       4/4     Running   0          66m
storage-0-1       4/4     Running   0          66m
```

Here is a description of the Volume claim and I do see the Claim bound for sparkhead-0 (data-sparkhead-0 and logs-sparkhead-0)

```
C:\Users\rgn>kubectl get pvc -n mssql-cluster
NAME               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
data-compute-0-0   Bound    pvc-13aa6838-7d94-4485-b362-5a93e3dff650   15Gi       RWO            default        18m
data-controldb     Bound    pvc-d0a98bd0-481d-4893-b7e3-4b0a3fe177c9   15Gi       RWO            default        26m
data-controller    Bound    pvc-636ee4dd-1ad4-49dc-921d-2a08b932bc6f   15Gi       RWO            default        26m
data-data-0-0      Bound    pvc-93a6c67f-aa73-4120-ac48-aa543bd4e256   15Gi       RWO            default        18m
data-data-0-1      Bound    pvc-3ef5af39-9434-4933-8e31-ba3454f3532e   15Gi       RWO            default        18m
data-gateway-0     Bound    pvc-2e66a32a-c1af-4fbc-bd6f-e486034f3fcf   15Gi       RWO            default        17m
data-logsdb-0      Bound    pvc-d3005d81-dfef-4eb7-9513-a9ffa22b25cf   15Gi       RWO            default        22m
data-master-0      Bound    pvc-5d94c6db-a061-4e48-9ac6-d9073405901c   15Gi       RWO            default        18m
data-metricsdb-0   Bound    pvc-b79e7de9-a996-4266-bd4b-e9757b74c286   15Gi       RWO            default        22m
data-nmnode-0-0    Bound    pvc-cb042a08-a55f-4911-aabd-dd71b8371674   15Gi       RWO            default        18m
data-sparkhead-0   Bound    pvc-b7090ce9-d3f7-4250-8327-4bb2e83ac64c   15Gi       RWO            default        17m
data-storage-0-0   Bound    pvc-ad248251-78af-4c82-a0c6-95aa78baeb72   15Gi       RWO            default        17m
data-storage-0-1   Bound    pvc-ca1eca42-9a9f-4db9-b844-a39fed60def0   15Gi       RWO            default        17m
logs-compute-0-0   Bound    pvc-883dafe4-76df-493b-8b3e-489ee3b26c10   10Gi       RWO            default        18m
logs-controldb     Bound    pvc-c0135496-3268-471a-958f-8bd3c9d346c6   10Gi       RWO            default        26m
logs-controller    Bound    pvc-0b2aba14-9272-4db9-bd35-12dd4d810ade   10Gi       RWO            default        26m
logs-data-0-0      Bound    pvc-92a13038-a14a-48fb-9a9f-7c92083087f8   10Gi       RWO            default        18m
logs-data-0-1      Bound    pvc-10e3668c-f172-47d2-86f3-cdff99763b36   10Gi       RWO            default        18m
logs-gateway-0     Bound    pvc-6d0525e3-83fb-480d-96f8-3d7e6778d3c0   10Gi       RWO            default        17m
logs-logsdb-0      Bound    pvc-81ad630a-e8d5-443e-9629-262a3b769819   10Gi       RWO            default        22m
logs-master-0      Bound    pvc-4cdbdf8f-ed9d-4fdc-bdb4-a776a6928868   10Gi       RWO            default        18m
logs-metricsdb-0   Bound    pvc-93e054bb-df90-4714-ae40-033a539316b7   10Gi       RWO            default        22m
logs-nmnode-0-0    Bound    pvc-6fd75daa-6a54-4ce0-8d82-e98e6c14dbad   10Gi       RWO            default        18m
logs-sparkhead-0   Bound    pvc-dd989502-b612-490c-95d0-2afa5127e5b1   10Gi       RWO            default        17m
logs-storage-0-0   Bound    pvc-6ffcfdc4-b1dd-4bd7-81b1-3b16aaa8b1c8   10Gi       RWO            default        17m
logs-storage-0-1   Bound    pvc-29ac02b3-c4f6-49f0-80bc-6551bae26fb6   10Gi       RWO            default        17m
```

Can someone point me on the right direction?

Thanks,
rgn

Comment: I think the problem is that you can create multiple pvc from the default sc, they the disks. But each node with the size Standard_E4s_v3 only can attach with 8 data disk. So when you mount the 25th data disk to the pod, it fails.

Comment: But it created the 26th drive. I understand if it fails on the 25 drive.

Comment: I didn't see it failed on create 25th PVC. It just failed on mount the 25th PVC on the pod.

Comment: Where does it say 25th PVC. I can count 26 PVCs from the list.

Comment: The PVC does not mean already attach. Only when you mount the PVC with disk to the pod, it means to attach to the node.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. For some reason I was thinking that I had listed out the PV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can create multiple pvc from the default sc, they the disks. But each node with the size Standard_E4s_v3 only can attach with 8 data disk. So when you mount the 25th data disk to the pod, it fails. – Charles Xu